# Deuteron magnetic moment for $l=2$

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, magnetic-moment

Considering the Deuteron in its $l=2$ state, I dont understand why its magnetic dipole moment is composed of $3$ terms:

$$ \mu_d = \mu_n + \mu_p + \mu_{orb}$$

where the first two are the intrinsic magnetic moments of the proton and neutron and the last one is the magnetic moment associated with the orbital contribution of the proton. What is the meaning of this last term? The proton isn't orbiting anything is it? And what about the electron dont we have to account for it's magnetic moment too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the electron: the "deuteron" is the nucleus, whose magnetic moment contributes to the magnetic moment of the atom, "deuterium."

Regarding the "orbital contribution of the proton": in any two-body systems, *both* objects orbit the center of mass. A good mechanics textbook will go show that that the two position vectors $\vec r_1, \vec r_2$ can be reduced to a single position vector $\vec r = \vec r_1 - \vec r_2$, and that this transformation gives a "one-body" equation of motion whose mass parameter is the "reduced mass" $\mu$ obeying $\frac1\mu = \frac1{m_1} + \frac1{m_2}$.  For systems with $m_1 \ll m_2$, such as an electron orbiting a nucleus or the Earth orbiting the Sun, the reduced mass is approximately equal to the lighter mass, and it's a good approximation to say that "the lighter object orbits the heavier object." However, the two nucleons in a deuterium nucleus have roughly equal masses, so they share the motion approximately equally.